# Subtraction not being evaluated in java? (caused by setting one array to another)

Tags: java

Note: this is not a duplicate of the many "why is my floating point subtraction giving exactly what I want?" The difference is in the 3rd decimal place.

I have the following in a java file:

```
perturb[i] = params[i]-h;
writer.write("    params "+Double.toString(params[i])+"\n");
writer.write("    h      "+Double.toString(h)+"\n");
writer.write("    pert1  "+Double.toString(params[i]-h)+"\n");
writer.write("    pert2  "+Double.toString(perturb[i])+"\n");
```

and the output file shows:

```
params 1.2E-7
h      1.2E-10
pert1  1.1987999999999999E-7
pert2  1.2E-7
```

perturb and params are both double[] and h is a double.

Why are pert1 and pert2 not the same? I can't seem to get perturb[i] to be params[i]-h.

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

The issue is there was a previous assignment of perturb to params (which apparently just makes perturb a reference to params). You can repeat the behavior with the following test case:

```
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] perturb;
    double[] params = {1.2E-7};
    perturb = params;
    double h=1.2E-10;
    int i=0;
    perturb[i] += h;
    perturb[i] = params[i]-h;
    System.out.println("    params "+Double.toString(params[i])+"\n");
    System.out.println("    h      "+Double.toString(h)+"\n");
    System.out.println("    pert1  "+Double.toString(params[i]-h)+"\n");
    System.out.println("    pert2  "+Double.toString(perturb[i])+"\n");

  }
}
```

which gives:

```
params 1.2E-7
h      1.2E-10
pert1  1.1987999999999999E-7
pert2  1.2E-7
```

Comment: Something about how your debugging this is wrong, the code is fine: http://ideone.com/x1ZIkK

Comment: @Mark. I also think the code is ok, but what could be wrong with my debugging? There is nothing between where I perform the subtraction, and print it to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you provided all code? Here is minimal code:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double []perturb={0.},params={1.2E-7};
        double h=1.2E-10;
        int i=0;
        perturb[i] = params[i]-h;
        System.out.println("    params "+Double.toString(params[i])+"\n");
        System.out.println("    h      "+Double.toString(h)+"\n");
        System.out.println("    pert1  "+Double.toString(params[i]-h)+"\n");
        System.out.println("    pert2  "+Double.toString(perturb[i])+"\n");

    }
}
```

and output:

params 1.2E-7

h      1.2E-10

pert1  1.1987999999999999E-7

pert2  1.1987999999999999E-7

Looks fine for me.

Comment: I just ran this, and it gives me the correct results... looking for possible differences between what's happening in my larger function. I didn't exclude anything from the snippet.

Comment: I found out the mistake. Earlier in the code it was assigning perturb = params. I've edited the question to that effect.